# Publish Bitbucket pipeline artifacts to a Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace-for-business, bitbucket

I am managing some documents in Git version control, hosted on Bitbucket.

Upon a push to Bitbucket, I would like the latest version of these documents to be visible to a select group of people.

It would be easy for us, if these docs were written to a Google Drive folder (which gives fine grain "share" permissions allowing fine-grained access control to the documents.

Is there an, off-the-shelf, solution for publishing Bitbucket Pipeline artifacts to a G Suite folder (via the GSuite API)? (Such as there are for other data stores like AWS).